# How to use fourier transform pair on image using opencv correctly?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, dft

Firstly, I utilize `putText` function to create a zero-filled image:

```
std::string text("Mengranlin");
int rows = 222;
int cols = 112;
double textSize = 1.5;
int textWidth = 2;
int num = 255;
cv::Mat zero_filled_img = cv::Mat::zeros(cols, rows, CV_32F);
putText(zero_filled_img, text, 
cv::Point(zero_filled_img.cols * 0.5, 
zero_filled_img.rows * 0.3),
cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, textSize, cv::Scalar(num, num, num), textWidth);
cv::Mat zero_filled_img2;
flip(zero_filled_img, zero_filled_img2, -1);
zero_filled_img += zero_filled_img2;
transpose(zero_filled_img, zero_filled_img);
flip(zero_filled_img, zero_filled_img, 1);
```

Here is the image:

[image: sssssss]

Secondly, I utilize inverse Fourier transform to the image:

```
int m = getOptimalDFTSize(rows);
int n = getOptimalDFTSize(cols);
cv::Mat dst;
copyMakeBorder(zero_filled_img, dst, 0, m - rows, 0, n - cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));
cv::Mat planes[] = { cv::Mat_<float>(dst), 
cv::Mat::zeros(dst.size(), CV_32F) };
cv::Mat complex;
cv::merge(planes,2, complex);
idft(complex, complex);
split(complex, planes);
magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);
```

Thirdly, I utilize Fourier transform to the result of inverse Fourier transform:

```
cv::merge(planes2, 2, complex);
dft(complex, complex);
split(complex, planes2);
magnitude(planes2[0], planes2[1], planes2[0]);
cv::Mat result = planes2[0];
```

Finally, I save the image:

```
result += 1;
log(result, result);
result = result(cv::Rect(0, 0, cols, rows));
int cx = result.cols / 2;
int cy = result.rows / 2;
cv::Mat temp;
cv::Mat q0(result, cv::Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));
cv::Mat q1(result, cv::Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));
cv::Mat q2(result, cv::Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));
cv::Mat q3(result, cv::Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy));
q0.copyTo(temp);
q3.copyTo(q0);
temp.copyTo(q3);
q1.copyTo(temp);
q2.copyTo(q1);
temp.copyTo(q2);
imwrite("./image/log_result.jpg", result);
```

Here is the image:

[image: sssssss]

Although the "Mengnalin" can be found from the image, that is very weak. And then, I save the normalization of the result, but I found nothing:

```
normalize(result, result);
imwrite("./image/normalize_result.jpg", result);
result *= 255;
imwrite("./image/normalize_result255.jpg", result);
```

Here is the normalization image:

[image: sssssss]

Here is the normalization image x 255:

[image: sssssss]

The experiment is successful when using Matlab. I want to know where the error is?

Below is the complete code that I ran:

```
std::string text("Mengranlin");
int rows = 222;
int cols = 112;
double textSize = 1.5;
int textWidth = 2;
int num = 255;
cv::Mat zero_filled_img = cv::Mat::zeros(cols, rows, CV_32F);
putText(zero_filled_img, text, cv::Point(zero_filled_img.cols * 0.5, zero_filled_img.rows * 0.3),
    cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, textSize, cv::Scalar(num, num, num), textWidth);
cv::Mat zero_filled_img2;
flip(zero_filled_img, zero_filled_img2, -1);
zero_filled_img += zero_filled_img2;
transpose(zero_filled_img, zero_filled_img);
flip(zero_filled_img, zero_filled_img, 1);
cv::Mat de = cv::Mat_<uchar>(zero_filled_img);
cv::imwrite("./image/zero_filled_img.jpg", zero_filled_img);

//idft
int m = getOptimalDFTSize(rows);
int n = getOptimalDFTSize(cols);
cv::Mat dst;
copyMakeBorder(zero_filled_img, dst, 0, m - rows, 0, n - cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));
cv::Mat planes[] = { cv::Mat_<float>(dst), cv::Mat::zeros(dst.size(), CV_32F) };
cv::Mat complex;
cv::merge(planes,2, complex);
idft(complex, complex);
split(complex, planes);
magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);
cv::Mat freq = planes[0];
freq = freq(cv::Rect(0, 0, cols, rows));
normalize(freq, freq, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);

//dft
cv::Mat planes2[] = {planes[0], planes[1]};
cv::merge(planes2, 2, complex);
dft(complex, complex);
split(complex, planes2);
magnitude(planes2[0], planes2[1], planes2[0]);
cv::Mat result = planes2[0];
//float min_v, max_v; min_max(result, min_v, max_v);
imwrite("./image/img.jpg", result);
result += 1;
imwrite("./image/img_plus_zero.jpg", result);
log(result, result);
result = result(cv::Rect(0, 0, cols, rows));
//float min_v1, max_v1; min_max(result, min_v1, max_v1);
imwrite("./image/log_img.jpg", result);
int cx = result.cols / 2;
int cy = result.rows / 2;
cv::Mat temp;
cv::Mat q0(result, cv::Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));
cv::Mat q1(result, cv::Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));
cv::Mat q2(result, cv::Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));
cv::Mat q3(result, cv::Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy));
q0.copyTo(temp);
q3.copyTo(q0);
temp.copyTo(q3);
q1.copyTo(temp);
q2.copyTo(q1);
temp.copyTo(q2);
normalize(result, result);
imwrite("./image/normalize_img.jpg", result);
result *= 255;
imwrite("./image/normalize_img255.jpg", result);
```

Comment: It is ok for that fourier transform is linear, and this is only a theory experiment.

Comment: I think there are some operating tricks when using opencv which confused me. so, could you find them. Thank you.

Comment: In addition, the matlab code work, here it is:   img = imread('original.jpg');
b = img(:,:,1);
foo = ifft2(b);

recover = fft2(foo);
recover = abs(recover/max(abs(recover(:))));
subplot(121);imshow(b);title('Original');
subplot(122);imshow(recover);title('recover');

Comment: These all be tried, and the code is just the final form.

Comment: Now that the imaginary part should be close to 0, and there is no error of division by 0. so I think magnitude is ok without the overflow, namely  numerical precision trick.

Comment: Try without the `log`. Also, your 2nd transform takes `planes2` as input, but that is not defined anywhere. Please post the code you actually ran. If you take the magnitude of the output of the first transform, you cannot do the inverse any more. Make sure you keep the complex values.

Comment: 1. I tried to remove the log operation. 2. Rearange the quadrants of the image should not affect the result.

Comment: You are right about the discuss of replacing magnitude with real part, thanks. And I post the whole code, however it do not work yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your code splits the output of `idft` into `planes[0]` (real component) and `planes[1]` (imaginary component), then computes the magnitude and writes it to `planes[0]`:

```
idft(complex, complex);
split(complex, planes);
magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);
```

Next, you merge `planes[0]` and `planes[1]` as the real and imaginary parts of a complex-valued image, and compute the `dft`:

```
cv::Mat planes2[] = {planes[0], planes[1]};
cv::merge(planes2, 2, complex);
dft(complex, complex);
```

But because `planes[0]` doesn't contain the real part of the output of `idft` any more, but its magnitude, `dft` will not perform the inverse calculation that `idft` did.

You can fix this easily. Instead of:

```
magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);
cv::Mat freq = planes[0];
```

Do:

```
cv::Mat freq;
magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], freq);
```

---

You can significantly simplify your code. Try the following code (`zero_filled_img` is the input image computed earlier):

```
// DFT
cv::Mat complex;
dft(zero_filled_img, complex, DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

// IDFT
cv::Mat result;
idft(complex, result, DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
imwrite("./image/img.jpg", result);
```

`result` should be equal to `zero_filled_img` within numerical accuracy.

The `DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT` flag forces the creation of a full, complex-valued DFT, even though the input array is real-valued. Likewise, `DFT_REAL_OUTPUT` causes any imaginary output components to be dropped, this is equivalent to computing the complex IDFT and then taking the real part only.

I have reversed the DFT and IDFT to be conceptually correct (though it is perfectly fine to reverse these two operations). `DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT` only works with the forward transform and `DFT_REAL_OUTPUT` only works with the inverse transform, so the code above will not work (I believe) if you use these two operations in the order you attempted in your own code.

The code above also doesn't bother with padding to a favourable size. Doing so might reduce computation time, but for such a small image it will not matter at all.

---

Note also that taking the magnitude of the output of the inverse transform (the second transform you apply) is OK in your case, but not in general. This second transform is expected to produce a real-valued output (since the input to the first one was real-valued). Any imaginary component should be 0 within numerical precision. Thus, the real component of the complex output should be kept. If you take the magnitude, you obtain the absolute value of the real component, meaning that any negative values in the original input will become positive values in the final output. In the case of the example images, all pixels are non-negative, but this is not necessarily true. Do the correct thing and take the real component rather than the magnitude.

Comment: Thanks for your carefull observation to my code and your advice.